# First order deformation isomorphic to the tangent space of moduli?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, moduli-space, deformation-theory

Let $\mathcal M$ be the moduli space of all smooth hypersurface of degree $d$ and dimension $n$. Is it true that
$$T_{[X]} \mathcal M \cong Def(X):=H^1(X,T_X)$$
holds for any such hypersurface $X$?

Any reference about this would be helpful.

Comment: I presume that the ambient scheme is $\mathbb{P}^{n+1}$. Fixing the degree fixes the Hilbert polynomial in this case say $P$. Then $\mathcal{M}$ is the Hilbert scheme. Now one just needs to understand tangent space at a point of a Hilbert scheme. This is just $H^0(X,N_{X/\mathbb{P}^{n+1}})$. What you wrote doesnot seem correct. But I am no expert.

Comment: @random123 No, $\mathcal M$ is not the Hilbert scheme. Isomorphic hypersurfaces should be regarded as one point in $\mathcal M$.